# Error with Expo fontFamily "material-community" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync

Tags: react-native, expo

I upgraded to expo 34.0.3 and related dependencies as below

```
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/samples": "3.0.3",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "expo": "^34.0.3",
    "expo-asset": "^5.0.1",
    "expo-font": "~6.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-34.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.3.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^7.5.0",
    "react-native-snackbar-component": "^1.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0"
  },
```

My App.js is presumably correctly preloading the fonts like so

```
  import * as Font from 'expo-font';
  import * as Icon from '@expo/vector-icons';

   .........


  _loadResourcesAsync = async () => {
    return Promise.all([
      Font.loadAsync({
        ...Icon.Ionicons.font,
        ...Icon.MaterialCommunityIcons.font,
      }),
    ]);
  };
```

Now just to be clear, this code was working just fine before the expo upgrade. 
This issue is seen on both Android and iOS devices.

[image: console error]

Comment: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/4217

Comment: thanks for pointing it out, I have downgraded Expo to 33.0 and everything is working as before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve this by deleting yarn.lock (I am using yarn) and removing node_modules after upgrade.
Then running yarn install again.

On the way I also upgraded expo cli, node and also used expo_codemod to take care of any upgrade related changes to my code. 
I also had to "expo install" packages that are moved out like react-native-gesture-handler

I think the key for me was to delete the lock files and also clear cache by expo start -c

Comment: Thanks you very match!
I did: ncu -u & npm install 
Apparently there is a bug in the versions: (the new version work fine)
 @use-expo/font  ^1.0.1  →    ^2.0.0
 expo ~36.0.0  →   ~37.0.6
 expo-font ~8.0.0  →    ~8.1.1
 react-navigation ^4.3.6  →    ^4.3.7
 react-navigation-stack ^2.3.10  →   ^2.3.11

Comment: but also there is a bug in react-navigation v4.x with font-family with expo-font 
that fix my Ionicicons font bug

Answer (score 17):

I have fixed the issue by using the following command in terminal

**rm -rf ./node_modules/expo/node_modules/expo-font/**

Comment: this should be the solution! worked perfectly

Comment: what this code is doing??

Comment: @kumaDK This code is a command used in a Unix-based terminal to delete the `expo-font` directory and all its contents, including any subdirectories. The `rm` command stands for "remove", the `-rf` options are used to force the removal of the directory and its contents recursively, and the `./node_modules/expo/node_modules/expo-font/` specifies the directory path to be removed.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly makesure to load scripts with correct path like below:

```js
 // Load fonts
        await Font.loadAsync({
          ...Ionicons.font,
          "space-mono": require("../assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf"),
          ionicons: require("@expo/vector-icons/build/vendor/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/Ionicons.ttf"),
          anticon: require("@expo/vector-icons/build/vendor/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/AntDesign.ttf"),
          "material-community": require("@expo/vector-icons/build/vendor/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf"),
        });
```

Following below steps fixed this issue (lang: typescript):

1. delete following lock files from the root directory

   - yarn.lock
   - package-lock.json
2. delete node_modules folder
3. run `npm install`
4. if you are using expo:

   - run `expo install`
   - run `expo start -c` to clear cache and start app

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this font issue by doing

```
# Like previous posts
rm -rf node_modules
rm yarn.lock
yarn install

# This command as well resolved the material-community issue for me.
expo install expo-font
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone using expo make sure to add `babel-preset-expo` in the `babel.config.js`

```js
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: []
  }   
}
```